# How can i display an image taken from file input?

Tags: javascript, html, web

I am new to web development and i am working on a project and wanted to be able to take an image as a file input, and then, on button press, to 'send' the image chosen, which is just displaying it. I have worked with a text input before, but i have no ideea how to handle file inputs. I searched and found another stackoverflow post that worked, but only for one image, so i tried to change it but didn't manage to accomplish anything. This was the code the response got (i am sorry to the person who gave this response, i can't find the post).

```js
var reader = new FileReader();
reader.onload = function (e) {
    $('#blah').attr('src', e.target.result);
}
   
   function readURL(input) {
        if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
            reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
        }
    }
    
    $("#imgInp").change(function(){
        readURL(this);
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <input type='file' id="imgInp" />
    <img id="blah" src="#" alt="your image" />
</form>
```

About the only thing i did was to convert the jQuery to vanilla JS, as what i tried other than that has failed miserably.
**Edit:** this was about what i got:

```js
let container = document.getElementById("messages");
let inp = document.getElementById("file");

let reader = new FileReader();
reader.onload = function (e) {
    container.innerHTML += `<img src="${e.target.result}" class="imgs">`;
}
   
function readURL(input) {
  if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
  // note: here i also tried to use a for loop in case there were multiple images, it didn't work
    reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
  }
}

inp.addEventListener("change", function(){
  readURL(this);
});
```

```css
/* some CSS to make it look better */

#btn {
  background: black;
  color: white;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  font-size: 30px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.imgs {
  max-height: 200px;
}

#file {
  transform: translateX(-999999999px);
  transform: translateY(-999999999px);
}
```

```html
<div id="interact">
  <div id="btn" onclick="document.getElementById('file').click()"> + </div>
</div>

<div id="messages">
  
</div>
<input type='file' multiple accept="image/*" id="file"/>
```

**Note:** i believe it was a syntax/naming mistake on my part; now it partially works, though it still cannot read multiple images at once.

I was hoping someone better versed into web development could help me out. Thank you in advance!

Comment: where do you want to send the image? Is it to a database?

Comment: @JoyDey not yet, there is no database yet, for now i want to just take the image and insert it in the document using innerHTML

Comment: But your snippet is working as you want

Comment: that is not my snippet, and it works for an image, but if instead of changing the source i use innerHTML to insert an image, the first time it works, but then, if you try to put another image after the first one, it doesn't work

Comment: can you update your code? I want to have a look at your innerHTML implementation

Comment: of course; also, i think, after a day of trying to get it to work, i think i'm close (i think it was a syntax/naming mistake); now i also put another button just to better simulate a the original project